# What is the ggplot2/plyr way to calculate statistical tests between two subgroups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I am a rather novice user of R and have come to appreciate the elegance of ggplot2 and plyr. Right now, I am trying to analyze a large dataset that I can not share here, but I have reconstructed my problem with the diamonds dataset (shortened for convenience).
Without further ado:

```
diam <- diamonds[diamonds$cut=="Fair"|diamonds$cut=="Ideal",]
boxplots <- ggplot(diam, aes(x=cut, price)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cut)) + facet_wrap(~ color)
print(boxplots)
```

[image]

What the plot produces is a set of boxplots, comparing the price of the two cuts "Fair" and "Ideal".

I would now very much like to proceed by statistically comparing the two cuts for each color subgroup (D,E,F,..,J) using either t.test or wilcox.test.

How would I implement this in an way that is as elegant as the ggplot2-syntax? I assume I would use ddply from the plyr-package, but I couldn't figure out how to feed two subgroups into a function that calculates the appropriate statistics..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(diam,"color",
      function(x) {
          w <- wilcox.test(price~cut,data=x)
          with(w,data.frame(statistic,p.value))
      })
```

(Substituting `t.test` for `wilcox.test` seems to work fine too.)

results:

```
  color statistic      p.value
1     D  339753.5 4.232833e-24
2     E  591104.5 6.789386e-19
3     F  731767.5 2.955504e-11
4     G  950008.0 1.176953e-12
5     H  611157.5 2.055857e-17
6     I  213019.0 3.299365e-04
7     J   56870.0 2.364026e-01
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking along the lines of splitting by color, but I couldn't figure out how to further proceed in the function... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

ddply returns a data frame as output and, assuming that I am reading your question properly, that isn't what you are looking for. I believe you would like to conduct a series of t-tests using a series of subsets of data so the only real task is compiling a list of those subsets. Once you have them you can use a function like lapply() to run a t-test for each subset in your list. I am sure this isn't the most elegant solution, but one approach would be to create a list of unique pairs of your colors using a function like this:

```
get.pairs <- function(v){
  l <- length(v)
  n <- sum(1:l-1)
  a <- vector("list",n)
  j = 1
  k = 2
  for(i in 1:n){
    a[[i]] <- c(v[j],v[k])
    if(k < l){
      k <- k + 1
    } else {
     j = j + 1
     k = j + 1
    }
  }
 return(a)
}
```

Now you can use that function to get your list of unique pairs of colors:

```
> (color.pairs <- get.pairs(levels(diam$color))))
[[1]]
[1] "D" "E"

[[2]]
[1] "D" "F"

...

[[21]]
[1] "I" "J"
```

Now you can use each of these lists to run a t.test (or whatever you would like) on your subset of your data frame, like so:

```
> t.test(price~cut,data=diam[diam$color %in% color.pairs[[1]],])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  price by cut 
t = 8.1594, df = 427.272, p-value = 3.801e-15
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 1008.014 1647.768 
sample estimates:
 mean in group Fair mean in group Ideal 
           3938.711            2610.820
```

Now use lapply() to run your test for each subset in your list of color pairs:

```
> lapply(color.pairs,function(x) t.test(price~cut,data=diam[diam$color %in% x,]))
[[1]]

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  price by cut 
t = 8.1594, df = 427.272, p-value = 3.801e-15
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 1008.014 1647.768 
sample estimates:
 mean in group Fair mean in group Ideal 
           3938.711            2610.820 

...

[[21]]

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  price by cut 
t = 0.8813, df = 375.996, p-value = 0.3787
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -260.0170  682.3882 
sample estimates:
 mean in group Fair mean in group Ideal 
       4802.912            4591.726
```

Comment: The OP asked for a plyr solution, which was perfectly possible using `ddply`. Even if you want the t.test objects in a list, and not the coefficients in a data.frame, you just use `dlpy` in stead of `ddply`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer! It does, however, test much more than I wanted: I really wanted to compare the price of cuts  in each color group, not the prices of each cut against all other colors.